# Lightbox2 2.6 shows images very tight

Tags: lightbox2

I'm using that library to show some pictures but when I open one of them the picture is very tight and smaller.

The code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $productThumb; ?>-1.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="<?php echo $productThumb; ?>-1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

The PHP variables contains the path to the image.

I tried using the older rel="lightbox" and the new data-lightbox

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look here, where it was first adressed: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/69, specifically [this](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/69#issuecomment-21787143).

So try adding this to your style sheet:

`.lb-image{
max-width: inherit;
}`

Answer (score 0):

try echoing the url to the big image in the A element, and the url to the thumbnail in the IMG element

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) I like that you start to give answer. You could make your answer more clear, by adding the line of code as it should be in your opinion.